# Bootstrap Dropdown Button within HoverCard

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [hovercard](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard/) to display a small profile card of a user. Within this hovercard I am attempting to include a Twitter Bootstrap dropdown button.

The button is being included in the html and the css is working fine (along with the actual javascript to open the dropdown). The problem is that the dropdown's menu cannot be seen.

Take a look at the image for a better explanation:
[image: example problem]

The 2nd example hovercard is the default result. As you can see, a small portion of the dropdown menu is being shown, but for some reason it is being hidden by the bounds of the hovercard box.

In the 1st example, I've removed the default bootstrap css position option and the dropdown inherits a position of static. When static is used, the menu can be seen but it increases the size of the hovercard box.

What I need to have happen, is when the carrot is clicked have the dropdown box/list open "on top" of the hovercard and not expand the hovercard's dimensions but instead have the dropdown act as it's own object with its own dimensions.

As an aside - I have checked both z-index's of the hovercard and the dropdown and the dropdown's z-index is higher so that should not be the issue.

EDIT:
Actual example markup

```
<div class="hc-preview" style="z-index: 0; "><a class="profilecard hc-name" rel="hovercard" data-type="custom" data-width="370" data-url="/omega/ajaxProfile/ProfileCard?eid=1" href="/omega/profile/profile/view/id/1" style="z-index: 0; "><img class="avatar thumb" src="/omega/images/1_darth-maul.png" alt="Avatar"></a><div class="hc-details" style="width: 370px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: none; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial; "><div class="s-card s-card-pad"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/omega/assets/5583cf06/css/bootstrap-yii.css">


<div class="hovercard">

<img class="thumb align-left" src="/omega/images/1_darth-maul.png" alt="Paul Johesphat"><h1>
Paul Johesphat<span class="badge badge-success" rel="tooltip" data-original-title="This person is an expert in our community">Expert</span></h1>
<h2>Advisor</h2>

<h2>
</h2>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div style="float:right; display:block;">

<div id="loading"></div>



<div id="connect-button1">
<div class="btn-group open">
  <button class="btn"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Friend</button>
  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
            <span class="instruct">Add to List:</span>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

<div id="list">
<li>
<a href="#" id="yt0">Acquaintance</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" id="yt1">Close Friend</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" id="yt2">Colleague</a></li>

<li>
<a href="#" id="yt3">Prospect</a></li>

</div>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a id="1" class="remove" href="/omega/friendship/friendship/removerequest">Remove Connection Request</a></li>
  </ul>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Try using the `.dropup` class combined with `.pull-right` ([see doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)). Or you could try exporting the menu outside of the vcard. Provide some generated html to get working examples.

Comment: Sherbrow, I tried the dropup and pull-right but unfortunately the same problem happened (of the hovercard box bounds cutting off the list) except this time, it was cutting it off at the top boundaries instead of the bottom. I've updated my post with actual code generated.

Comment: Set `position: absolute;` for `.btn-group`.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a `overflow: hidden` problem.

You should try applying the style `overflow: visible` to the parent tree of the dropdown-menu. It may be around `<div style="float:right; display:block;">`.

Comment: Sherbrow, thank you for the comment. I've tried adding overflow:visible to every different parent of the ul group in the dom tree and none of them resulted in being able to view the drop down menu. I can see exactly what your line of thinking was though! The ul dropdown list is being "buried" inside the hovercard when in fact it should be "above" the hovercard and expand as long as it needs to. I can't figure out how to bring it "out" of the hovercard though.